# SSRS Security Audit

Tags: ssrs

Is there a way to audit access given to reports \ folder in SSRS ? 
Trying to figure out who granted browser access to a user to a specific folder.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to start with this query:

```
select u.UserName, c.Name as ItemName, 
    CASE (c.Type)
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Folder'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Paginated Report'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Embeded Files'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Data Sources'
        WHEN 8 THEN 'Data Sets'
        WHEN 13 THEN 'PowerBI Report'
    ELSE 'Unknown' End as ItemType,
    c.Path
from [Catalog] as c 
        join PolicyUserRole as pur on c.PolicyID = pur.PolicyID
        join Users as u on pur.UserID = u.UserID
```

Comment: This gives what access a user has. But I am trying to figure out who granted that access.

Comment: I don't think (by default) in SSRS such audit info available. you may want to create audit/trigger on `PolicyUserRole` table.